# Ideal HTML semantics for Customer Review

Tags: html, semantics

I need to include a few customer reviews on my page and am unsure if my approach is semantically and practically correct.
I might be overthinking this a little bit, so input would be welcome!

I would like to include the  element in the Heading, which is also part of the figure. There would then be no fig caption.

```
       <section>
       <figure>            
           <h3><cite>Claire</cite></h3>
           <img src="5stars.png" alt="5 stars">
           <blockquote>
               <p>I really benefit from this product, every single day</p>
           </blockquote>
           <figcaption>
           <!-- nothing to add here, citing Claire again would be redundant -->
           </figcaption>
       </figure>
       </section>
```

An alternative would be to include the blockquote as the caption to the 5-star image

```
       <section>
       <figure>            
           <h3><cite>Claire</cite></h3>
           <img src="5stars.png" alt="5 stars">
           <figcaption>
           <blockquote>
               <p>I really benefit from this product, every single day</p>
           </blockquote>
           </figcaption>
       </figure>
       </section>
```

The way most tutorials show is the citation in the figcaption, but I don't like that the heading doesn't really serve a purpose.

```
        <section>
            <h3>Claire's review</h3> <!-- Title would likely be hidden from page -->
        <figure>
            <img src="5stars.png" alt="5 stars">
            <blockquote>
                <p>I really benefit from this product, every single day</p>
            </blockquote>
            <figcaption>
                <cite>Claire Bis</cite>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
        </section>
```

Or maybe even more complex, but why not?

```
        <section>
        <header>
        <h3>Claire's review</h3> <!-- Title would likely be hidden from page -->
        <img src="5stars.png" alt="5 stars">
        </header>
        <figure>
            <blockquote>
                <p>I really benefit from this product, every single day</p>
            </blockquote>
            <figcaption>
                <cite>Claire Bis</cite>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the `<blockquote>` tag to directly quote Claire and appending the star rating within the element would be more than sufficient, no need to add unnecessary complexity to the accessibility tree/DOM depth with `<figure>/<figcaption>`.

```
<section>           
    <h3>Claire's review</h3>
    <blockquote>
       <p>I really benefit from this product, every single day.</p>
       <img src="5stars.png" alt="5 stars"/>
    </blockquote>
 </section>
```

In addition, the [`<cite>` tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-cite-element) is reserved for the names of creative works or media, not people.

> A person's name is not the title of a work — even if people call that person a piece of work — and the element must therefore not be used to mark up people's names. (In some cases, the `<b>` element might be appropriate for names; e.g. in a gossip article where the names of famous people are keywords rendered with a different style to draw attention to them. In other cases, if an element is really needed, the `<span>` element can be used.)

Comment: Great thanks ! What if I would like to have "Claire's review" underneath the review? Would a figure + figcaption & hidden heading be appropriate? Or would working with a footer be better?

Comment: Nesting `<footer>Claire's review</footer>` within the `<blockquote>` would be the best way to go about it.

Comment: No, not _within_ the blockquote - it's not what's being quoted. Within the section element would be fine. The HTML specification contains [an example](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element:the-blockquote-element-5) of using figcaption for the attribution, so that would be fine too.

Comment: Interesting you say that, because within the blockquote is exactly how it's presented in [MDN's demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blockquote).

Comment: The blockquote element's semantics has a complicated history. Prior to HTML5, the blockquote was strictly to contain the quoted text. Earlier in the HTML5 era we had competing specifications, one from WHATWG and one from W3C. The W3C one, for a while, did approve of placing content inside the blockquote element beyond what was being quoted, and I suspect that's where MDN's example comes from. Whereas the WHATWG version never did.

Comment: Eventually the conflict between the W3C and WHATWG was resolved, with the the W3C deferring to the WHATWG specification. We can only really go by the current specification so the MDN's example is not correct.